# .htaccess for dynamic subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, nginx

My situation is:

1. I want to make subdomains on domain dynamicaly, so

1.1. I added to domain's nginx config this:

```
root /home/site.ru/public_html/$subdomain;
set $subdomain "";
if ($host ~* ^([a-z0-9-\.]+)\.site.ru$) {
    set $subdomain $1;
}
if ($host ~* ^www.site.ru$) {
    set $subdomain "";
}
```

1.2. I added to domain's apache config that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.site.ru$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((.*)\.)site.ru$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /%2/$1
```

2.1 On (root)domain i have a wordpress with his .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.site\.ru
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

2.2. On subdomain (that i added as folder) i have a custom dynamic php-script with his own .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

And it's works but not so well - css files doesn't seems, and opens only index page like bla.site.ru, but another links on that subdomain doesn't work. 
I will be grateful for it, if you'll help with this (I've googled two hours but there is no solution with my situation - `.htaccess` for subdomain script - nobody makes dynamic subdomains may be :) ).